# Python ignores indentation and continues to run code as part of the class in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, recursion, indentation

Ok, this one might be totally stupid but here goes. I create a simple class in python using VSCode.
I then create an instance of the class and it just keeps running and creating instances until I get
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded, as if the unindented code was part of the class.

```
class Account:
   def __init__(self, initialCash):
      self.money = initialCash
      print("New account created. Initial budget: " + self.money)

   @property
   def money(self):
      return self.money

   @money.setter
   def money(self, value):
      self.money = value

account2 = Account(100)
```

The indentation is 3 spaces, automatic, as set in VSCode settings. What am I missing?

Comment: You should use 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.money` calls the setter, which calls the setter, which ...

You have to rename the attribute:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, initial_cash):
        self._money = initial_cash
        print(f"New account created. Initial budget: {self.money}")

    @property
    def money(self):
        return self._money

    @money.setter
    def money(self, value):
        self._money = value
```